# How can a private person donate food to the Palestinians now?

Tags: palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, food, humanitarian-aid

How can a private person participate in food-aid to the Palestinians at this time? A necessary condition is making sure that the donation indeed goes to food only.

Please explain how it is possible to verify that the donation goes to food only.

---

Question by an Israeli Jew.

Comment: Thank you for a great question. Delivering humanitarian supplies **directly** to the Palestinian civilians is a worthwhile goal. **As of now, there are no easy answers.** See the answer to this question for reasons why: [Is there clear public evidence for Netanyahu's assertion that Hamas is stealing the food aid at gunpoint, enough to affect the civilians in Gaza?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/86464/28554)

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if, given that we have 2 close votes - *"not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes"* - this Q couldn't be rephrased to something like *"What actions can a Jewish Israeli citizen take to improve the food situation in Gaza?"*.  That would be more on topic politically:  write your representative, participate in protests, *donate food* ...

Answer (score 4):

[World Central Kitchen](https://wck.org/en-us/news/balsam) opened a Welcome Center in [Deir al-Balah](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Deir+al+Balah/@31.4161941,34.3207733,12.5z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x14fd84c2293da045:0x8c3c868834340e87!8m2!3d31.417139!4d34.350931!16zL20vMDU0MjMx?entry=ttu) in central Gaza to greet Palestinians fleeing south in search of safety. Hundreds of people cross the checkpoint from north to south each day to escape relentless bombardment and lack of food. WCK is simultaneously providing as much aid as possible in northern Gaza and supporting displaced people who come through they Welcome Center.

This organization, founded by the celebrity Spanish chef has served more than 32 million meals in Gaza, and he hopes to do more ([The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/03/07/world/middleeast/world-central-kitchen-gaza-aid.html?ugrp=m&unlocked_article_code=1.f00.7mhk.iwh8WfQqEx7s&smid=url-share)).

They are ready to accept the donations. They are really focused on food.

Comment: Hi, I edited the OP. Please explain how it is possible to verify that the donation goes to food only.

Comment: This can be checked via references to the sources that could be seen as more or less reliable. I added the reference from The New York Times. WCK is the internationally recognized organization with long operation history.

Comment: [Times of Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/aid-from-cyprus-to-enter-gaza-via-idf-built-pier-eu-warns-of-pockets-of-famine/)  *The ship was to be inspected by the Israeli Navy at sea once it gets to around 20 nautical miles from the Gaza coast, according to information seen by The Times of Israel.*  This is for their sailing from Cyprus.

Answer (score 0):

The WFP also [accepts](https://www.wfp.org/support-us) direct (money) donations from individual donors.

TBH, I'm not sure it's possible to donate either to this or to "World Central Kitchen" and ensure your donation goes *only* to [food for] Gaza, since they run world-wide programs.

FWTW, WCK [claims](https://www.fastcompany.com/91056471/chef-jose-andres-world-central-kitchen-food-gaza-israel-war) to serve around 350,000 meals per day in Gaza. The WPF around 300,000 [it seems](https://twitter.com/WFP/status/1772940377336545391), but that probably doesn't include [parcels](https://www.wfp.org/emergencies/palestine-emergency). BTW, although the 200-ton ship made headlines, WCK shipped most of their food by truck from Egypt -- around 1,600 of them [to date](https://wck.org/news/41m-meals-gaza). That page also says the WCK serves around 170,000 *hot* meals per day in Gaza. Somewhere in the [fine print](https://www.eatingwell.com/world-central-kitchen-feed-displaced-israeli-palestinian-families-8364003), WCK partners with [Anera](https://www.anera.org/blog/gaza-and-west-bank-response-log/) for the local activities in Gaza. The latter is a US-registered charity as well, but they're focused on Palestinians. Anera does more than food themselves though, so if you dislike that, don't give to them directly. The Israeli press [criticized](https://www.i24news.tv/en/news/international/americas/1702399547-taylor-swift-and-selena-gomez-join-star-studded-fundraising-event-for-gaza) Anera for not condemning Hamas, so there's that too.

Actually, [since 2022](https://unric.org/en/sharethemeal-wfp-app-marks-new-milestone/) (and possibly earlier), the WFP claims to allow small-share donors to direct their contributions to specific zones, through the [Share-the-meal app](https://sharethemeal.org/en-us/campaigns#).
(N.B. ShareTheMeal has been around since around 2014-2015, when the WFP resorted to them because they [faced](https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2015/nov/12/world-food-programme-share-the-meal-app-syrian-children) a severe shortage in governments-provided funding for the Syrian refugees aid.) OTOH, besides being under the UN aegis, which some Israelis might find objectionable in itself, WFP also [gives](https://humanitarianfundingforecast.org/stories-agency-expenditure/) a non-trivial amount as cash assistance rather than just food. Their (logistics) overhead is also larger than that of other organizations (around 1/3--the WFP personnel overhead though is only around 14% though), enough that the CharityWatch [doesn't](https://www.charitywatch.org/charity-donating-articles/gaza-israel-conflict-top-rated-charities-providing-aid) list the WFP, unlike the WCK. (They only list orgs with less than 25% overhead.) You can also look at the latter list for other ideas/orgs, but most that operate in the region aren't food-only.

Comment: Aside the WFP definitely [differentiates](https://www.wfp.org/funding/2022) between "flexible" and "directed" contributions from the bigger (country) donors. The latter go to specific countries.

Comment: ... but the 'flexible' ones are only around 5% these days https://academic.oup.com/view-large/figure/426048185/oso-9780198755173-graphic-117.gif