# What are the practical implications for the World Food Programme being "an international organization within the United Nations"?

Tags: united-nations, food

AFAICT the WFP budget is entirely separate from that of the UN, although they do get [mostly](https://academic.oup.com/book/39139/chapter/338583523#426048037) contributions from governments. All WFP contributions are voluntary, none are 'due' or assessed (unlike for some other UN-linked organizations).  OTOH that chapter mentions that WFP "Members are drawn from the UN system of state classifications." I'm not entirely sure what are the implications of that, if any.

So, what are the practical implications for the World Food Programme being "an international organization within the United Nations", as opposed some other food-oriented charity/NGO like World Central Kitchen or Oxfam etc.?

Comment: What are you asking? It seems like this is an organization for countries to take part in rather then induvial or private organizations and there are only a couple of countries that are not members of the UN.

Comment: @JoeW: WFP [accepts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/86638/18373) private contributions too. I suppose the main diff is in governance, which is what I'm trying to find out here.

Comment: I understand that it may accept private donations but that doesn't mean it isn't designed for governance by countries. I am not sure what makes this one different then any other organization that is part of the UN.

Comment: @JoeW: I'm not sure that's the case. Most WFP executive directors were from the US (and in fact all since 1992) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Food_Programme#List_of_executive_directors So it looks it's decided based on the main source of funding, in practice.

Comment: I am not sure that most directors being from the US has anything to do with it being part of the UN. There are other organizations in the UN that are not dominated by US leadership and ones outside it that are.

Comment: I read a news article today on CNBC that said that the world's richest 1% have $44 trillion dollars. I can only hope that these blessed individuals will contribute more money to the World Food Programme and other charitable organizations around the world.

Comment: @user57467 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giving_Pledge As of last year, the total pledged is about $600 billion, so around 1% of the wealth of the top 1%.